# Finding number of points within each respective polygon in table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have:

- a shapefile of circles at 15 meters radius and
- point data with GPS coordinates.

How can I **count the number of points within each circle** and have a raw number that can show such? I've tried spatial joins, but I can't seem to find the proper way to determine the number of points.

Comment: Spatial Join should automatically add a field Join_Count. This will be the number of matching features.

Comment: I figured it out, was joining the wrong layer, resulting in the wrong values being displayed. Thanks for the help!